# Automated posting on a myspace blog

Tags: myspace

I intend to automatically post an article teaser on a myspace blog when I publish it on another website. Is this possible using one of the [official APIs](http://wiki.developer.myspace.com/index.php?title=Category:RESTful_API) or will I have to get down to the nitty-gritty and do this manually?
I know the ["Share on myspace"](http://wiki.developer.myspace.com/index.php?title=Share_on_MySpace) mechanism, but it does not allow to do blog posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a [plugin](http://manual.b2evolution.net/Post2myspace_plugin) for the cms b2evolution that should provide enough help to write an own solution. Other suggestions are still welcome.